# How to remove certain number of lines every time particular string is found in file

Tags: sed, awk, solaris

I want to remove 1 previous line and 10 following lines every time a string was found in the file.

`foo.txt`:

`}
Name: john
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10
Line 11
Line 12
Apple
orange
grape
pine
}
Name: Ruben
Line 
Line 
Line 
Line 
Line 
Line 
Line 
Line 
Line 
Line 
grape
zebra
donkey
}
Name: Tom
Line 
Line 
Line 
Line 
Line 
Line 
Line 
Line 
Line 
Line 
Tiger
red
blue
orange
tomato
cat
}`

Desired `Out.txt` :

`Name: john
Apple
orange
grape
pine
Name: Ruben
grape
zebra
donkey
Name: Tom
Tiger
red
blue
orange
tomato
cat`

I want to use `sed` or `nawk`. The flower brace and the next 10 lines after Name: should go away. Using Solaris 5.10 with `ksh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using awk

```
$ awk '/}/{next;} /Name:/{print;n=NR+10} NR>n' file
Name: john
Apple
orange
grape
pine
Name: Ruben
grape
zebra
donkey
Name: Tom
Tiger
red
blue
orange
tomato
cat
```

#### How it works

- `/}/{next;}`

  Skip over any line containing `}`.
- `/Name:/{print;n=NR+10}`

  When we reach a line containing `Name:`, print it and, so we know when to start printing again, set `n` to 10 plus the current line number.
- `NR>n`

  If the current line number is greater than `n`, then do the default action: print the line.

### Using sed

With very similar logic:

```
$ sed -e '/}/d' -e '/Name:/{p;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;d;}' file
Name: john
Apple
orange
grape
pine
Name: Ruben
grape
zebra
donkey
Name: Tom
Tiger
red
blue
orange
tomato
cat
```

#### How it works

- `/}/d`

  Delete any line containing `}`.
- `/Name:/{p;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;d;}`

  If we find a line containing `Name:`, print it, then read in the next 10 lines and delete them.

Lines not falling into either the above categories are printed.